# Limite de exibição de páginas em estrutura de paginação

Tags: php, paginação

- Estou montando um estrutura simples de paginação e até então está funcionando.
- Está estrutura tem links chamados de: 
  Anterior - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - Próximo

Minha dúvida é como fazer para criar um limite de exibição, exemplo: Estou na página 1, terá que exibir os links de 1 até 5 e se eu clicar no link 5 aparece do 2 ao 6 se eu clicar no 6 aparecer 3 ao 7 e assim por diante.

```
<?php

// Estrutura básica de paginação

$limit = 10; // Limite de registros por página
$cont  = 1;  // Contator
$qtdRegistros = 80; // Quantidade de registros no banco
$qtdPaginas = ceil(($qtdRegistros/100)*$limit); // Quantidades de páginas a ser exibida 


// Verifica se está vázio, se estiver irá colocar o valor 1 
if(empty($_GET['page'])){
    $_GET['page']=$cont;
}


$backPage = $_GET['page']-1;
$advancePage = $_GET['page']+1;


// Verifica se está na primeiro página. Se estiver o botão anterior não é exibido
if($_GET['page'] !=1){
    echo "<a href='?page=$backPage'>Anterior - </a>";
}   

while ($cont <= $qtdPaginas) {
    echo "<a href='?page=$cont'>$cont</a>"; 
    $cont++;    
}


// Verifica se está na última página. Se estiver o botão próximo não é exibido
if($_GET['page'] != $qtdPaginas){
    echo "<a href='?page=$advancePage'> - Próximo </a>";
}


    echo "</br>";


if(isset($_GET['page'])== $cont){
    if($_GET['page'] <= $qtdPaginas){
        $url=$_GET['page'];
        echo "Página atual é:".$url."</br>";
    }else{
        echo "Página não encontrada";
    }
}

// Explicação.. 

// ceil() -- Arredonda para cima - 
// $qtdPaginas -- Pega a quantidade de registros(50) divide por 100 = 0,5 multiplica pelo limite (10) = 5, ou seja 5 páginas.

?>
```

Comment: A lógica básica é colocar a página atual no centro do intervalo que você quer mostrar. Se está na página 10 e quer mostrar 5 por vez, você mostra da 8 à 12 (ou seja, duas antes e duas depois). A conta é simples. As pontas (primeiras e últimas páginas) são exceções.

Comment: Cara, eu fiz isso uma vez com PHP puro e foi coisa de doido. Depois eu vi que era desperdício de tempo e eu poderia utilizar o DataTables.

Comment: Como estou em aprendizado, estou tentando fazer na unha mesmo, mas estou com dificuldade em montar está lógica.

Answer (score 5):

logica : (pagina = pagina atual, paginas = total paginas)

```
if pagina != 1 mostra link pag1 (primeira)...
for (i = pagina -4; i <= pagina +4; i++) {
  if (i > 1 and i < pagina - 4 and i < paginas and i < pagina + 4) mostra link pagina=i
}
if pagina != paginas link ...paginas (ultima)
```

por exemplo pagina atual 14, total de paginas 50. 
Eu abstrai a linguagem intencionalmente

vai aparecer : 1... 10 11 12 13 14 15 18 17 18 ...50

Answer (score 0):

Valeu Galera, consegui montar o código colocando um for dentro do outro. Funcionou bem.

```
<?php

// Estrutura básica de páginação 

$limit = 10; // Limite de registros por página
$cont  = 1;  // Contator
$qtdRegistros = 200; // Quantidade de registros no banco
$qtdPaginas = ceil(($qtdRegistros/100)*$limit); // Quantidades de páginas a ser exibida 


// Verifica se está vázio, se estiver irá colocar o valor 1 
if(empty($_GET['page'])){
    $_GET['page']=$cont;
}

$backPage = $_GET['page']-1;
$advancePage = $_GET['page']+1;


// Verifica se está na primeiro página. Se estiver o botão anterior não é exibido
if($_GET['page'] !=1){
    echo "<a href='?page=$backPage'>Anterior - </a>";
}   


for($cont;$cont<=$limit;$cont++){
    if($cont<=5){
        echo "<a href='?page=$cont'>$cont</a>";
    }

    if($_GET['page']>5){
        for($j=$_GET['page']-2;$j<=$_GET['page']+2;$j++){
                echo "<a href='?page=$j'>$j</a>";
                if($j>=$qtdPaginas){
                    break;
                }
            }   
            break;
    }
}       


// Verifica se está na última página. Se estiver o botão próximo não é exibido
if($_GET['page'] != $qtdPaginas){
    echo "<a href='?page=$advancePage'> - Próximo </a>";
}


echo "</br>";


if(isset($_GET['page'])== $cont){
    if($_GET['page'] <= $qtdPaginas){
        $url=$_GET['page'];
        echo "Página atual é:".$url."</br>";
    }else{
        echo "Página não encontrada";
    }
}

// Explicação.. 

// ceil() -- Arredonda para cima - 
// $qtdPaginas -- Pega a quantidade de registros(50) divide por 100 = 0,5 multiplica pelo limite (10) = 5, ou seja 5 páginas.


?>
```